# adding lines to your AndroidManifest.xml file - fail to provide permission

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, permissions

I already placed the permission to allow external storage of document and potentially list all PDF documents. Despite adding the lines to your AndroidManifest.xml file, the error message keeps appearing when widget is launched.

Please advise how to fix this error message.

[image]

```
Exception has occurred.
FileManagerError (    

    Try to add thes lines to your AndroidManifest.xml file

          `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
          `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

    and grant storage permissions to your applicaion from app settings
    

FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13))
```

This is the method where the error comes from:

```
  void getFiles() async { //asyn function to get list of files
      List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
      var root = storageInfo[0].rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, geting the root directory
      var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
      files = await fm.filesTree( 
        excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/Android"],
        extensions: ["pdf"] //optional, to filter files, list only pdf files
      );
      setState(() {}); //update the UI
  }
```

Comment: Did you clean the project with `flutter clean` ? If not, clean it and rerun your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Add the following package to the `pubspec.yaml` file:

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler

```
dependencies:
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
```

Then you can request storage permission:

```
if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
  // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
}
```

Comment: thanks, where do you place the request storage permission?

Comment: before calling the method to access the files